# Close nodes of polygons

Tags: qgis

I have a lot of polygons which look like this:

[image: close nodes in polygons]

In QGIS geometry checker there is no error even with a tolerance of 10^-3. But in an Online-ArcGIS System (10^-3 tolerance) it seems that it detects an self-intersection at this point. Is there any possibility to find this points in QGIS?

The files are Shape-Files from an external Programm. I have to take them like they are. So the correction have to be in QGIS. Most Polygons have more that 60k Points and in the shapefiles are sometimes more that 50k features.

Comment: How are you checking validity in QGIS with tolerances?

Comment: Did you know you can create a File geodatabase in ArcGIS and define the XY resolution? If the default resolution is too large, just make it smaller, so your nearby Points are not detected as a self intersection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mapshaper.org](http://mapshaper.org/). When you drag and drop your shapefile it will automatically detect line intersections. You can use simplify tool to simplify your geometries then again export your file as shapefile.